# Yocto Transaction Test, two recipes install the same file

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am adding a custom recipe to my image. It is bases on [DBCPPP](https://github.com/xR3b0rn/dbcppp). This project is built using `cmake`. My issue only comes to light when I include a new layer `meta-swupdate`. It seems `meta-swupdate` alters the kernel in a way that conflicts with `dbcppp`. My full error is:

```
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.10 conflicts between attempted installs of dbcppp-1.0+gitr0+fa8ce17468-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon and libxml2-2.9.10-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon
```

To build and include `dbcppp` I added the recipe:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "gitsm://github.com/xR3b0rn/dbcppp.git;protocol=https;branch=master"
PV = "1.0+gitr${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

DEPENDS += " boost"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig cmake

FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/xml2Conf.sh /usr/lib/lib*.so.*"

SOLIBS = ".so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "dev-so"
```

I have read a few other questions and attempted two solutions by adding a `do_install_append` step.

1. Change folder permission level `install -d 0755 ${D}/usr/lib`
2. Remove the folder `rm -rf ${D}/usr/lib`

Neither solution worked. I need both libraries in my application and I unsure how to proceed.

Edit: After some further reading I found a suggestion to delete the `tmp`, `cache`, and `sstate-chace` folders. I did this but I receive the same error.

Edit: My `local.conf` has `PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= 'package_rpm'` defined. if I remove this I still get a `do_rootfs` error, but the error message is not helpful.

Edit: In my recipe for dbcppp I have attempted to remove the file in question. This gives me the same error. Makes no difference.

```
do_install_append() {
    rm -rf /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.10
}
```

Comment: Removing the file with `do_install_append` from one recipe should work in this situation. You can check in `build/tmp/work/` if there are in image directory in both packages that library. If so, your `do_install_append` is not good.

Comment: Updating my question to respond to this.