# Replace LibXML2 with Yocto Built LibXML2

Tags: cmake, embedded-linux, yocto, cmakelists-options

I have been working on this all day, but I think I finally have my base case figured out. I am using a GitHub repo [DBCPPP](https://github.com/xR3b0rn/dbcppp) in my application. This repo relies on `LibXml2`, to ensure it is available `LibXml2` is included as a submodule and build with `dbcppp` through a series of `CMakeLists.txt`. I am trying to resolve an issue with my build in which the Linux kernel and the DBCPPP recipe are both attempting to install `/usr/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.10`. I have an open question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75249522/yocto-transaction-test-two-recipes-install-the-same-file).

My potential solution is to prevent DBCPPP from creating the `libxml2.so.2.9.10` file, and instead build using the `libxml2.so.2.9.10` file created by Yocto.

So far my `CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project("libdbcppp" VERSION 0.1.0)

set(LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR /mnt/WorkDrive/Documents/EVCC_Application/build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libxml2/2.9.10-r0/libxml2-2.9.10/include)
set(LIBXML2_LIBRARIES /mnt/WorkDrive/Documents/EVCC_Application/build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libxml2/2.9.10-r0/image/usr/lib)

#include(FindPkgConfig)
#include(FindLibXml2 REQUIRED)
find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)

option(build_tests "Build tests" ON)
option(build_examples "Build examples" ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
    add_definitions("/bigobj")
endif()

include_directories("include")
include_directories("third-party/libxmlmm/libxmlmm")
include_directories("/mnt/WorkDrive/Documents/EVCC_Application/build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/boost")
include_directories("/mnt/WorkDrive/Documents/EVCC_Application/build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libxml2/2.9.10-r0/libxml2-2.9.10/include")
include_directories("third-party/cxxopts/include")

file(GLOB libxmlmm_header
    "third-party/libxmlmm/libxmlmm/*.h"
)
file(GLOB libxmlmm_src
    "third-party/libxmlmm/libxmlmm/*.cpp"
)

add_library(libxmlmm SHARED "")
target_link_libraries(libxmlmm LibXml2::LibXml2)

target_sources("libxmlmm"
    PRIVATE ${libxmlmm_header}
    PRIVATE ${libxmlmm_src}
)


install(TARGETS "libxmlmm" EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}Targets DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
install(
    DIRECTORY "libxmlmm"
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/libxmlmm
    FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")

set(CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

CONFIGURE_FILE(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake.in"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake"
  IMMEDIATE @ONLY
)

ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(uninstall
  "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake"
)
```

Edit: I am updating my question with my latest `CMakeLists.txt`. I am integrating this with a Yocto project. This appears to work within Ubuntu but when I added it to the Yocto build I get the error.

```
error: /mnt/WorkDrive/Documents/MAIN_Application/build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/libxml2/2.9.10-r0/image/usr/lib: read: Is a directory
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

Comment: You link with `LibXml2`, but [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindLibXml2.html) for `FindLibXml2.cmake` module clearly tells how to use its results: either as `LibXml2::LibXml2` IMPORTED library (preferred) or via variables `LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `LIBXML2_LIBRARIES` and `LIBXML2_DEFINITIONS`. You set variable `LIBXML2_LIBRARIES` for hint about location of libraries, but the documentation tells to use `LIBXML2_LIBRARY` cache variable. You include `Find*` modules via `include` command, but `find_package` should be used instead (e.g. `find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I believe you solved my issue. I now get the error file format not recognized. I believe this is a cross compiler issue.

Comment: Concerning your settings of variables `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES` and `CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES`, see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42017111/cmake-error-required-internal-cmake-variable-not-set). (In short: Instead of defining those variables make your `project()` call to be the second instruction in your `CMakeListst.txt`, after `cmake_minimum_required`).

Comment: I am attempting to place this into a yocto build. I cannot call cmake from the CLI. I will update with my current file